# change shapre of img

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I need help with Transform moving square image to circle in html canvas

I have imported a image that is a square. I want that image be round and still move.

Goal:

- square image to circle image, and still able to move.

I have tried alot of tutorial on stackoverflow mainly with c. stroke and c.split but when I apply those the image doesnt move anymore.

Does someone have any suggestions?

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

function Circle() {
    //Give var for circle
    this.x = 10;
    this.y = 100;
    this.dx = 1;
    this.dy = 1;
    this.radius = 50;
    this.diameter = 2 * this.radius;

    //Get external square picture (Needs to be converted in circle)
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/2607/large/molecular_future.png?1547036754";

    //Draw circle on canvas
    this.draw = function () {
        //Circle
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, (this.radius*1), 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        c.closePath();

        //TODO: cut square to circle

        //Place square (image) on top of the circle
        c.drawImage(image, (this.x-this.diameter/2) , (this.y-this.diameter/2), this.diameter, this.diameter);
    };

    //Update position
    this.update = function () {
        this.x += this.dx;
        this.draw()
    }
}

//Animate canvas
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
    this.update();
}

//Start
Circle();
animate();
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: black;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<canvas></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by generating your composed image and then use it in your animation code.

To make such a compositing, you'd better use compositing than clipping, because clipping is an all or nothing operation, it won't deal well with the antialiasing required by a circle.

To store this composed image in a convenient way, you can either use a second canvas, or in newest browsers an [ImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap), both will then be drawable by [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).

Here is an ES5 implementation, using a second canvas and a callback:

```js
// older browsers version
function makeCircleImage(radius, src, success, failure) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = canvas.height = radius * 2;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = src;
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // we use compositing, offers better antialiasing than clip()
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
    ctx.arc(radius, radius, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();
    success(canvas);
  };
  img.onerror = failure;
}
var url = "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/2607/large/molecular_future.png?1547036754";
makeCircleImage( 50, url, function( canvas ) {
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
}, console.error );
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: black;
}
```

And here is one that you can use in newest browsers which will store an ImageBitmap (preferable when available for memory and <sub>theoretical</sub> speed of drawing).

```js
// newest browsers version
function makeCircleImage( radius, src ) {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    // this canvas will get Garbage Collected
    const canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
    canvas.width = canvas.height = radius * 2;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
    img.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
      // we use compositing, offers better antialiasing than clip()
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
      ctx.arc( radius, radius, radius, 0, Math.PI*2 );
      ctx.fill();
      resolve( createImageBitmap( canvas ) );
    };
    img.onerror = reject;
  });
}

async function init() {
  const url = "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/2607/large/molecular_future.png?1547036754";
  const img = await makeCircleImage(50, url);
  document.querySelector('canvas')
    .getContext('2d')
    .drawImage(img, 0,0);
};
init().catch( console.error );
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Now that we have a clear source ready to use, all our we have to do in the animation code is to put these pixels, without any heavy computation:

```js
// older browsers version
function makeCircleImage(radius, src, callback) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = canvas.height = radius * 2;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = src;
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // we use compositing, offers better antialiasing than clip()
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
    ctx.arc(radius, radius, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();
    callback(canvas);
  };
}

function Circle( x, y, radius ) {
  //Give var for circle
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.dx = 1;
  this.dy = 1;
  this.radius = radius;
}
// use prototyping if you wish to make it a class
Circle.prototype = {
//Draw circle on canvas
  draw: function () {
    var
      x = (this.x - this.radius),
      y = (this.y - this.radius);
    // draw is a single call
    c.drawImage( this.image, x, y );
  },
  update: function () {
    var
      max_right = canvas.width + this.radius,
      max_left = this.radius * -1;
    this.x += this.dx;
    if( this.x > max_right ) {
      this.x += max_right - this.x;
      this.dx *= -1;
    }
    if( this.x < max_left ) {
      this.x += max_left - this.x;
      this.dx *= -1;
    }
  },
  init: function(callback) {
    var url = "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/2607/large/molecular_future.png?1547036754";
    makeCircleImage( this.radius, url, function(img) {
      this.image = img;
      callback();
    }.bind(this));
  }
};

//Animate canvas
function animate() {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  circles.forEach(function( circle ) {
    circle.update();
  });
  circles.forEach(function( circle ) {
    circle.draw();
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var circles = [
  new Circle(10, 100, 50),
  new Circle(10, 200, 30),
  new Circle(10, 300, 50)
];
var ready = 0;
circles.forEach(function(circle) {
  circle.init(oncircledone);
});
function oncircledone() {
  if(++ready === circles.length) {
    animate()
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: black;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<canvas></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

And for newest browsers:

```js
// newest browsers version
function makeCircleImage( radius, src ) {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    // this canvas will get Garbage Collected
    const canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
    canvas.width = canvas.height = radius * 2;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
    img.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
      // we use compositing, offers better antialiasing than clip()
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
      ctx.arc( radius, radius, radius, 0, Math.PI*2 );
      ctx.fill();
      resolve( createImageBitmap( canvas ) );
    };
    img.onerror = reject;
  });
}


class Circle {
  constructor( x, y, radius ) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dx = 1;
    this.dy = 1;
    this.radius = radius;
  }
  draw() {
    const x = (this.x - this.radius);
    const y = (this.y - this.radius);
    c.drawImage( this.image, x, y );
  }
  update() {
    const max_right = canvas.width + this.radius;
    const max_left = this.radius * -1;
    this.x += this.dx;
    if( this.x > max_right ) {
      this.x += max_right - this.x;
      this.dx *= -1;
    }
    if( this.x < max_left ) {
      this.x += max_left - this.x;
      this.dx *= -1;
    }
  }
  async init() {
    const url = "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/2607/large/molecular_future.png?1547036754";
    this.image = await makeCircleImage( this.radius, url );
  }
}

//Animate canvas
function animate() {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  circles.forEach( (circle) => circle.update() );
  circles.forEach( (circle) => circle.draw() );

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const c = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

const circles = [
  new Circle(10, 50, 50),
  new Circle(10, 150, 30),
  new Circle(450, 250, 80)
];

Promise.all(circles.map( (circle) => circle.init() ))
  .then(animate)
  .catch(console.error);
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: black;

}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

But if you are going to have a lot of Circle instances and that they will only differ in their radius, but share the same original image's source, then you might prefer to store a single high quality version of the composed image and just rescale it in each instance's draw call.

```js
// newest browsers version
function makeCircleImage( radius, src ) {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    // this canvas will get Garbage Collected
    const canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
    canvas.width = canvas.height = radius * 2;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
    img.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
      // we use compositing, offers better antialiasing than clip()
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
      ctx.arc( radius, radius, radius, 0, Math.PI*2 );
      ctx.fill();
      resolve( createImageBitmap( canvas ) );
    };
    img.onerror = reject;
  });
}

(async () => {
const url = "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/2607/large/molecular_future.png?1547036754";
const image = await makeCircleImage(250, url); // original size of the png image
class Circle {
  constructor( x, y, radius ) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dx = 1;
    this.dy = 1;
    this.radius = radius;
  }
  draw() {
    const x = (this.x - this.radius);
    const y = (this.y - this.radius);
    // now they all use the same image
    // with a bit more computation though due to resizing
    c.drawImage( image, x, y , this.radius * 2, this.radius * 2);
  }
  update() {
    const max_right = canvas.width + this.radius;
    const max_left = this.radius * -1;
    this.x += this.dx;
    if( this.x > max_right ) {
      this.x += max_right - this.x;
      this.dx *= -1;
    }
    if( this.x < max_left ) {
      this.x += max_left - this.x;
      this.dx *= -1;
    }
  }
}

//Animate canvas
function animate() {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  circles.forEach( (circle) => circle.update() );
  circles.forEach( (circle) => circle.draw() );

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const c = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

const rand = (n) => Math.random() * n;
const circles = Array.from({ length: 50 })
  .map( () =>
    new Circle(
      rand(canvas.width),
      rand(canvas.height),
      rand(125)
    )
  );

animate();

})()
.catch(console.error);
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: black;

}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to use `context.clip();` in your case `c.clip();` this creates a clipping filter on the canvas that you can then draw in. Before you make a clip you must make a save and then restore after you draw with `c.save();` and `c.restore()` respectively.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
var circles = [];

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

function Circle() {
    //Give var for circle
    this.x = 100;
    this.y = 100;
    this.dx = 1;
    this.dy = 1;
    this.radius = 50;
    this.diameter = 2 * this.radius;
    this.size = null;
    this.c = null;

    //Get external square picture (Needs to be converted in circle)
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/2607/large/molecular_future.png?1547036754";

    //Draw circle on canvas
    this.draw = function () {
        //Circle
        this.c.beginPath();
        this.c.arc(this.x, this.y, (this.radius*1), 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        this.c.closePath();
        this.c.save();
        this.c.clip();
        //TODO: cut square to circle

        //Place square (image) on top of the circle
        this.c.drawImage(image, (this.x-this.diameter/2) , (this.y-this.diameter/2), this.diameter, this.diameter);
        this.c.restore();
    };

    //Update position
    this.update = function () {
        if(this.x - this.radius <= 0 || this.x + this.radius >= this.size.x){this.dx = -this.dx}
        
        this.x += this.dx;
        this.draw()
    }

    this.init = function(options) {
      
       Object.keys(options).forEach((key)=>{
          this[key]=options[key];
       })
    }
}

//Animate canvas
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
    for(let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++){ circles[i].update(); }
}

//Start
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i-=-1){
    let circle = new Circle();
    circle.init({
        x: Math.random() * window.innerWidth,
        y: Math.random() * window.innerHeight,
        size: {x: window.innerWidth,y: window.innerHeight},
        c
    })
    circles.push(circle)
}
animate();
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: black;

}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<canvas></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help it worked! The only problem I have now is when I spawn more Circles in with a higher move speed it lags crazy, with this implementation (normally it doesnt). Do you have a workaround or other optimalization tips?

Comment: @AttackTheWar i made some edits to your code to allow for instantiating the objects and also to allow them to bounce back and forth but as you can see even 20 objects bouncing back and forth work fine. i think it might have been the way you were instantiating them.

Comment: Thanks again! I'm spawning 100 objects in the canvas. Without the square to circle transformation everything is running smooth. When using the code you provieded me. It is lagging like crazy. So probably I have to do something with the image before the this.draw function. Somewhere in the Circle function. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: how are you instantiating the Circle function? in the code above i have made it so that it Creates 100 circles and is running smoothly